# Can't redirect to login page because of 403 error, security.JwtAuthenticationFilter : Received token from request: null

Tags: authentication, cors, http-status-code-403

I am building an integrated environment, and both the front and back ends succeeded in generating tokens. However, I am experiencing 403 error and both the backend and frontend seem to be working fine. I am not sure where the error is occurring. It shows a fetch error, not a cors error, and when it is a 403 error, it says to redirect from the  ApiService.js file in the front code to the login page, but it does not show a todo error on the todo page, the page you can enter after logging in.

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import com.example.demo.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(request -> {
            CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
            config.setAllowCredentials(true);
            config.addAllowedOriginPattern("http://localhost:3000"); // 변경된 부분
            config.addAllowedHeader("*");
            config.addAllowedMethod("*");
            return config;
        }))// CORS 설정
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()) // CSRF 설정 비활성화
            .httpBasic(httpBasic -> httpBasic.disable()) // HTTP Basic 인증 비활성화
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)) // 세션 관리 설정

.authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeRequests) ->
                authorizeRequests
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/auth/**","/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )

            .addFilterAfter(jwtAuthenticationFilter, CorsFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

This is WebSecurityConfig.java in Backend

```
package com.example.demo.security;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            // 요청에서 토큰 추출 및 로깅
            String token = parseBearerToken(request);
            log.info("Received token from request: {}", token);

            if (token != null && !token.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                // 토큰 검증 및 로깅
                String userId = tokenProvider.validateAndGetUserId(token);
                log.info("Authenticated user ID: {}", userId);

                // 인증 완료; SecurityContextHolder에 등록
                AbstractAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userId,
                        null,
                        AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES
                );
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
                securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
                SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseBearerToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is JwtAuthenticationFilter.java in Backend Spring boot Eclipse

```
package com.example.demo.security;

import com.example.demo.model.UserEntity;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Date;
import java.security.Key;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class TokenProvider {
    private static final Key key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512);

    public String create(UserEntity userEntity) {
        // 기한을 현재부터 1일로 설정
        Date expiryDate = Date.from(
                        Instant.now()
                        .plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS));

        // JWT Token 생성
        return Jwts.builder()
                // header에 들어갈 내용 및 서명을 하기 위한 시크릿 키
                .signWith(key)
                // payload에 들어갈 내용
                .setSubject(userEntity.getId()) // sub
                .setIssuer("demo app") // iss
                .setIssuedAt(new Date()) // iat
                .setExpiration(expiryDate) // exp
                .compact();
    }

    public String validateAndGetUserId(String token) {
        // parseClaimsJws 메서드가 Base64로 디코딩 및 파싱.
        // 즉, 헤더와 페이로드를 setSigningKey로 넘어온 시크릿을 이용해 서명 후, token의 서명과 비교.
        // 위조되지 않았다면 페이로드(Claims) 리턴
        // 그 중 우리는 userId가 필요하므로 getBody를 부른다.
        Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(key)
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();

        return claims.getSubject();
    }
}
```

This is TokenProvider.java in Backend

```
// ApiService.js

import { API_BASE_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN } from "../app-config";

export function call(api, method, request) {
  let headers = new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  });

  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN);
  if (accessToken && accessToken !== null) {
    headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
  }

  let options = {
    headers: headers,
    url: API_BASE_URL + api,
    method: method,
  };

  if (request) {
    options.body = JSON.stringify(request);
  }

  return fetch(options.url, options)
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.status);
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      if (error.message === "403") {
        window.location.href = "/login";
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
}

export function signin(userDTO) {
  return call("/auth/signin", "POST", userDTO).then((response) => {
    if (response.token) {
      localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, response.token);
      window.location.href = "/";
    }
  });
}

export function signout() {
  localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, null);
  window.location.href = "/login";
}

export function signup(userDTO) {
  return call("/auth/signup", "POST", userDTO);
}
```

And this is ApiService.js in Frontend.

error message is
'Request URL:
http://localhost:8080/todo
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
403 Forbidden
:
[::1]:8080
Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
http://localhost:3000
Cache-Control:
no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Length:
0
Date:
Sun, 10 Mar 2024 13:19:33 GMT
Expires:
0
Keep-Alive:
timeout=60
Pragma:
no-cache
Vary:
Origin
Vary:
Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary:
Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options:
nosniff
X-Frame-Options:
DENY
X-Xss-Protection:
0
Accept:
*/*
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language:
en-US,en;q=0.9,ko;q=0.8
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Type:
application/json
Host:
localhost:8080
Origin:
http://localhost:3000
Referer:
http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Chromium";v="122", "Not(A:Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="122"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:
same-site
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

And Also preflight occurs well.

I checked all codes in backend, Frontend. I Checked Tokens.  I can sign in with POST commands from the backend to postman on my own. It doesn't seem to be a CORS error. If I see authorizer token on the front end, it works fine. Tokens both generate normally, but they don't seem to be allowed on the backend.